# EF Core 8.0 Child Relationship with Other Key

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am trying to have the Child property of Parent join on OtherId. However, no combination of foreign, principal, etc. has resulted in success.

I typically get the: *The foreign key must target a type that is part of the relationship.* error.

What's the correct way to get this to work.

```
public class Parent
{
   public int Id
   public int OtherId { get; set; }        
   public Dependent Child { get; set; }
}

public class Dependent
{
   public int OtherId { get; set; }        
   public string Name { get; set; }        
}
```

I've tried various versions of the following:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>()
            .HasOne(x => x.Child )
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey<Child >(x => x.OtherId )
            .HasPrincipalKey<Parent>(x => x.OtherId )
            .IsRequired(false);
```

Comment: Can you add how the model is configured? Or you are not explicitly configuring relationships?

Comment: I don't have anything specific that's worked. I've updated the post with the current configs that errored out

Comment: You have `.IsRequired(false);` but your `int OtherId` properties are not nullable.

Answer (score 0):

For an optional one-to-one with a FK:

```
public class Parent
{
   public int Id
   public int? OtherId { get; set; }        
   public Dependent? Child { get; set; }
}

public class Dependent
{
   public int OtherId { get; set; }        
   public string Name { get; set; }        
}

modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>()
    .HasOne(x => x.Child )
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey<Parent>(x => x.OtherId);
```

The `HasForeignkey` is enough, where the `<Parent>` vs `<Dependent>` indicates which side of the relationship holds the FK. By default that FK will point to the PK on the other side, so in this case the "OtherId" in the Dependent which would be the PK of that table. `HasPrincipalkey` is used when the FK points to something other than the PK on the target table (Dependent), which does not appear to be the case here.

`IsRequired(false)` is implied with the null-able FK. For a required relationship, Make the OtherId and Child navigation property in the Parent non-nullable. Again, `IsRequired(true)` would be implied. The use for `IsRequired(true)` is mainly when you want a null-able navigation property to keep compile time warnings happy around unset reference variables, while still telling EF that the relationship is required.